# Weighted linear regression in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, weighting

I would like to do a linear regression with a weighting factor for an analytical chemistry calibration curve.  The x values are concentration and assumed to have no error.  The y values are instrument response and the variation is assumed proportional to concentration. So, I would like to use a 1/x weighting factor for the linear regression.  The data set is simply ten concentrations with a single measurement for each.  Is there an easy way to do this in R?  .

Comment: `lm` takes a `weights` argument. So you could calculate the weights, and store them either in a separate vector or in your dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

The answer can be found on a somewhat older question on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7513/how-to-use-weights-in-function-lm-in-r). The `lm()` function (which represents the usual method of applying a linear regression), has an option to specify weights. As shown in the answer on the link, you can use a formula in the `weights` argument. In your case, the formula will likely take the form of `1/data$concentration`.

As suggested by hrbrmstr, I'm adding [mpiktas's actual answer from Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/7530):

> I think R help page of lm answers your question pretty well. The only
>   requirement for weights is that the vector supplied must be the same
>   length as the data. You can even supply only the name of the variable
>   in the data set, R will take care of the rest, NA management, etc. You
>   can also use formulas in the weight argument. Here is the example:
>
> ```
> x <-c(rnorm(10),NA) df <-
> data.frame(y=1+2*x+rnorm(11)/2,x=x,wght1=1:11)
>
> ##Fancy weights as numeric vector 
> summary(lm(y~x,data=df,weights=(df$wght1)^(3/4))) 
>
> #Fancy weights as formula on column of the data set
> summary(lm(y~x,data=df,weights=I(wght1^(3/4))))
>
> #Mundane weights as the column of the data set
> summary(lm(y~x,data=df,weights=wght1)
> ```
>
> Note that weights must be positive, otherwise R will produce an error.